# Was the reason for the Loud family having so many children ever addressed in the show, or in real ife?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-loud-house

In the Loud House, was the reasons for the Loud Family having so many children ever addressed within the show's canon (For example were they planned?), or confirmed in real life by the show's writers\producers during an interview, etc?

Comment: Because Mr Loud can't keep it in his pants

Comment: Neither [allegedly] could the show's creator. ;)

Answer (score 3):

**In-universe:**

There are some hints in the show that Rita is religious. She prays for her family's safety on various occasions and the family is shown as attending church-run events such as picnics and cookouts. The family is also shown (in the Loud House movie) to be related to Scottish royalty which would track with a Catholic tradition, but it's not spelled out *overtly*, presumably to avoid alienating any portion of the show's potential audience.

---

**Out-of-universe:**

The show is based on the life and experiences of the show's creator; Chris Savino. He was born into a large family. His parents were Catholics and evidently didn't believe in using birth control.

> **Q. What is your life like now and how do you feel today as opposed to before you found God?**
>
> **CS:** *Although **my parents were Catholic,** church was not a part of my life growing up. **As child number nine out of ten,** you can understand that getting the entire brood out the door on a Sunday morning would have been difficult. I wasn’t baptized as a child and did not seek religion of any sort most of my adult life. And why should I? My life was going very well and I was in control. I could take care of myself.*
>
> <sub><sup>[From Nickelodeon Cartoonist to Redemption in Jesus: An Interview with Chris Savino](https://www.dailyrenegade.com/amp/from-nickelodeon-cartoonist-to-redemption-in-jesus-an-interview-with-chris-savino)</sup></sub>